# Database permissions for DB User in cd_storage_config.xml

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, configuration, database

In an SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 implementation, what are the minimum/recommended rights that the #DB_USER# must have. In the documentation ([login required](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html#&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF&pubid=SDL_Tridion_2011&publang=en-US&resource=&docid=task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF&filename=ConfiguringContentBroker.xml)) I can see

> the name of a user who can access the database.

Does this mean dbreader/dbwriter other/more?

Perhaps I've missed something in the documentation in which case I'd appreciate a pointer as I'd also like to ensure clarity on the minimum levels for other Tridion specific database users.

Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="#client_db_#DBID#" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="#DB_SERVER_NAME#" />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="#DB_PORT#" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="#DB_NAME#" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="#DB_USER#" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="#DB_PASSWORD#" />
    </DataSource>
</Storage>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tridion Database Manager tool automatically creates a user for you and sets rights according to the needs of this user. The following Role memberships are set:

- db_datareader;
- db_datawriter;
- public;

Additionally, the user is granted the Connect permission on the database pand Login permission on the database instance.

Additionally a Schema is created with the same name as the user, which is used to set the datareader / datawriter role on the Broker database.

Comment: Thanks Raimond. The best way would have been to test in a clean environment but without access, your pointer is great - confirmed this with the limited access just fine.